# Need to display image when user click clickme button

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, actionlistener

I need to display image in label when the user click the button.I have written some code in ActionListener but its not working

```
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ImageIcon one = new ImageIcon("E:\\image1.jpg");
            panel_1.setLocation(20, 100);
            panel_1.setSize(115, 115);
            mbutton.setIcon(one);
            panel_1.add(mbutton);
            // mbutton.setText("You changed me");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hopefully this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) might be able to help you a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Im a bit confused as to your code you talk of adding an image to a `JLabel` but the code shows you adding a variable `mButton` and setting its icon, which makes me think its `JButton`?

Either way is the `JLabel`/`JButton` already added to the container or is it being added dynamically too?

1) If `JLabel`/`JButton` is not already present on visible container:

After adding/removing or changing size/Layout of components on a visible container, you should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on containers instance as to reflect the changes:

```
//code which adds component to visible panel_1

//so changes can be reflected
panel_1.revalidate();
panel_1.repaint();
```

2) If `JLabel`/`JButton` is visible `setIcon` should work as it calls `revalidate()` and `repaint()` itself as seen here from `JLabel#setIcon` (`JButton` is the same):

```
     * 108: getfield      #294                // Field defaultIcon:Ljavax/swing/Icon;
     * 111: invokeinterface #346,  1          // InterfaceMethod javax/swing/Icon.getIconHeight:()I
     * 116: aload_2
     * 117: invokeinterface #346,  1          // InterfaceMethod javax/swing/Icon.getIconHeight:()I
     * 122: if_icmpeq     129
     * 125: aload_0
     * 126: invokevirtual #319                // Method revalidate:()V
     * 129: aload_0
     * 130: invokevirtual #318                // Method repaint:()V
```

thus something else is at fault like your LayoutManager not correctly supporting the addition of the new component and thus it doesnt get placed in a visible space, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Also I see you are using `setSize(..)` and `setLocation(..)` so I get the feeling you are using the `Absolute`/`null` `LayoutManager` this is not recommend and can cause many problems. Rather use an appropriate `LayoutManager` see here for more:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)